# How can I create a section of fields with angular2 json schema form?

Tags: angular, forms, jsonschema

I'm using https://github.com/dschnelldavis/angular2-json-schema-form and my form HTML is:

```
<json-schema-form
[schema]="schema"
(onSubmit)="exampleOnSubmitFn($event)">
</json-schema-form>
```

My `schema` is:

```
this.schema = {
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    CCN: {
      required: true,
      type: "number",
      minimum: 1000000000,
      maximum: 99999999999999999999
    },
    Quarter: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      enum: ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4']
    },
    Year: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      enum: ['2018', '2019', '2020']  
    },
    covered_medi: {
      title: "Covered by Medicare/Medicaid",
      type: "number",
      required: true
    },
    covered_private: {
      title: "Covered by private insurance",
      type: "number",
      required: true
    },
    Uninsured: {
      type: "number",
      required: true
    },
  }
}
```

I want `Quarter` and `Year` to be in a separate section. I tried using the `layout` property:

```
this.layout = [{
  type: "fieldset",
  title: "Reporting Period",
  items: [{
    key: "Quarter"
  }, {
    key: "Year"
  }]
}]
```

But that seems to not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have [installed and instantiated the provider](https://github.com/dschnelldavis/angular2-json-schema-form#to-install-from-npm-and-use-in-your-own-project). The only thing that can fail is the schema, [examples](https://github.com/dschnelldavis/angular2-json-schema-form/tree/master/src/demo/assets/example-schemas), or the callback, test with an empty one.

ts

```
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent {

   public schema: any = {...}
   public onSubmit(event) {...}
   ... }
```

html

```
<json-schema-form
  [schema]="schema"
  (onSubmit)="onSubmit($event)">
</json-schema-form>
```

In this [example](http://json-schema.org/examples.html), put the required out of each property.